# Simple Semigroup (of operator) inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators

I have been able to show that the norm $\| x \|_{1} : = \sup_{t \geq 0} \| T(t)x \|$ is equivalent to the norm $\| x \|$, where $T$ is a bounded $C_0$-semigroup. I  now want to show that $T$ is a contractive $C_0$-semigroup. That is, $\| T(t) \|_1 \leq 1$. I keep getting the inequality in reverse however, that is, $\| T(t) \|_1 \geq 1$:

$$\| x \|_{1} = \sup_{t \geq 0} \| T(t) x \|  \leq  \sup_{t \geq 0} \| T(t) \| \cdot \| x \| \leq \sup_{t \geq 0} \| T(t) \| \sup_{t \geq 0} \| T(t)x\|.$$ Can someone point out what I'm missing?

Comment: Do you want to prove something about $\|T(t)\| = \sup \{\|T(x)x\| \, : \, \|x \| \le 1\}$? This need not be bounded by 1 if $T$ is a bounded $C_0$ semigroup.

Comment: @HansEngler I want to show $T$ is a contractive $C_0$-semigroup with the norm given by $\| x \| = sup_{t \geq 0} \| T(t)x \|$.

Comment: OK. Please fix the question so the notation is clear. To prove this you should use the semigroup property.

Comment: So you want to show $\Vert T(t) \Vert_1 \leq 1$?

Comment: @SahibaArora Yes.

Comment: Please edit your question to fix the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\|T(t)x\|_1 = \sup_{s \geq 0} \| T(s)T(t)x \| = \sup_{s \geq 0} \| T(s+t)x \| \leq \sup_{t+s \geq 0} \|T(t+s)x\| = \|x\|_1 $$

Comment: Doesn't this show that $\| T(t) \|_1 \geq 1$?

Comment: @David Fixed it. Thanks.